# GUI program (gitkraken) won't start in fedora docker

Tags: docker, fedora, gitkraken, x11-forwarding

I'm having trouble starting a Gitkraken (latest) in a fedora-based docker on windows.

```
 export DISPLAY=168.1.23:0.0 && gitkraken  <---- exits immediately with exit code 0 :-(
```

Which is strange, because this works fine:

```
 export DISPLAY=192.168.1.10 && xeyes      <---- works
```

And in WSL (running Ubuntu) I have no problems starting gui applications like this:

```
 export DISPLAY=192.168.1.10 && xeyes        <---- works
 export DISPLAY=192.168.1.10 && gitkraken    <---- works
```

The host machine is Win10 running vcxserver (without problems I suspect, since xeyes and firefox etc start fine)

It must be some strange incompatibility with the packages in the fedora-docker.
How do I examine this?

I tried "strace gitkraken" ... which obviously gives a lot of info ...

What can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running GitKraken with the flag `--disable-gpu` to disable hardware acceleration.